# How can I DISTINCT users with MAX recent date but different data between them in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I need to select the most recent purchase of each client in the same query. My problem: when there is a customer with several purchases and the CODE field is different, it shows me all of them.

This is an example to simplify my question:

**My_DE:** 6 rows

| CLIENT | SKU | DATE | CODE |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678X | 1632 | 23/04/2021 | 26 |  |
| 12345678X | 1632 | 25/05/2021 | 12 |  |
| 12345678X | 1632 | 22/01/2022 | 99 |  |
| 92345678Z | 1467 | 24/01/2022 | 78 |  |
| 82345678H | 1233 | 18/01/2022 | 56 |  |
| 72345678F | 1988 | 24/01/2022 | 42 |  |

**My Query**

```
SELECT
    CLIENT
   ,SKU
   ,MAX (DATE) AS DATE_MAX
   ,CODE
FROM [My_DE]
Group by
    CLIENT
   ,SKU
   ,CODE
```

The result includes to CLIENT "12345678 X" 3 times. The reason is that the CODE field is different. How can I get that in cases like this, only the one with the most recent DATE field is returned, even though there is a different CODE field?

Thanks

Comment: I know a lot of people feel that this is too SQL specific to match the purpose of Salesforce SE, but as the SFMC SQL Query Activity is a major part of SFMC and is also unique compared to 'normal' T-SQL, I feel these types of questions are definitely valid and viable for this site. Plus issues like these are likely to be had by multiple people coming here or googling that helps resolve these issues within a related context and not requiring them to go via another site which they may not know to look at.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a partition in this case.  It's my go-to for most deduplication scenarios:

```sql
select top 1 with ties
  d.client
, d.sku
, d.[date] date_max
, d.code
from My_DE d
order by row_number() over (partition by d.client order by d.[date] desc)
```

The `row_number() over (partition by` will number rows from 1 to x for each unique combination of the proceeding fields (in your case `d.client`), sorted by the `order by` clause.  The `top 1 with ties` gives you all the rows that where `row_number()` is `1`.

**Edit**: Here's the long form of this query:

```sql
select 
  x.client
, x.sku
, x.[date] date_max
, x.code
from (

    select
      d.client
    , d.sku
    , d.[date] date_max
    , d.code
    , row_number() over (partition by d.client order by d.[date] desc) rowNum
    from My_DE d 

) x
where x.rowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Although adding a partition is a useful and strong solution like @AdamSpriggs hase - I usually tend towards utilizing WHERE statements in this situation.

If you set a WHERE statement to only get the record when DATE equals MAX(Date) of that record, then only one will return. See below example:

```sql
SELECT 
  CLIENT, 
  SKU, 
  MAX(Date) AS DATE_MAX, 
  CODE
FROM [myDE] a
WHERE DATE = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(Date) FROM [myDE] b WHERE b.Client = a.Client)
GROUP BY
  CLIENT, SKU, CODE
```

Which returns:

```
client     |  sku   |  date_max             |  code  |
12345678X  |  1632  |  Jan 22 2022 12:00AM  |  99    |
92345678Z  |  1467  |  Jan 24 2022 12:00AM  |  78    |
....etc...
```

As to which is more performant or any such thing, I am not positive, but I do not see there being a significant difference. I personally find this way easier to read, but others may like the partition by. I just wanted to share another option as a potential solution.